# Flutter: Non-Overlapping / Dynamic Positioning of widget

Tags: android, flutter, flutter-layout, launcher, android-launcher

Stack Widget can be used along with Positioned Widget / Align Widget / Using Stack’s Alignment Property to have multiple children widgets placed(For ex- Container widget) inside Stack.

**Example Reference:**

1. https://www.flutterbeads.com/flutter-position-widget-in-stack/
2. https://medium.flutterdevs.com/stack-and-positioned-widget-in-flutter-3d1a7b30b09a

**Issue:**

1. Children widgets overlaps on each other.
2. When a new widget is placed inside a Stack widget, it does not dynamically position itself based on space available. (For ex- I have placed **3 Container** widgets inside **Stack widget**. When I place **4th Container widget** inside **Stack widget**, it should automatically position itself based on space available on the screen. Similar to the functionality of a Home Launcher application- Widget gets added on the Screen if there is available space).

**Desired Behavior(Similar to a Home Launcher application):**

1. Widget can be added dynamically (with no-overlap) onto the screen. It should place itself based on space available.
   Link: [GIF: Launcher Add Widget functionality](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nojp9.jpg)
2. Widget can be re-positioned (with no-overlap) through drag and drop once added onto the screen.
   Link: [GIF: Launcher Reposition functionality](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y7tm0.jpg)
3. Based on the change of position of a widget, Other widgets present on the screen get re-positioned automatically.

> Could someone please help if there is a way to handle it (In Flutter) with the
> existing approach / Alternative widgets which can be used in place /
> Custom widget concept, if available?

Comment: There are multiple ways a widget can "dynamically position itself based on space available". Solution to your problem will depend on what kind of behaviour are you trying to achieve, so please explain this in your question.

Comment: @mfkw1 - I want to achieve behavior (using Flutter) similar to that of a Home Launcher application. I had added GIF files in the question(Section - Desired Behavior) to show the use cases. Requesting you to please check once.

Comment: Unfortunately, this kind of behavior is too complex to be built into Flutter itself. You should probably implement it by yourself by using [`CustomMultiChildLayout`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/CustomMultiChildLayout-class.html)

Comment: @mfkw1 Thank you for your help. I was able to implement this logic with the help of CustomMultiChildLayout.